# Django @csrf_exempt doesn't work on webfaction server?

Tags: python, ios, django, http-post, django-csrf

My iOS app need send POST request to Django.
I use **"@csrf_exempt"** to disable to **"CSRF"**. **On local**, iOS and Django works very well.
But after I deploy the website to to the **"webfaction"**, the Django can not get the iOS POST request.
My question is how to deal with this problem about CSRF, need I do some other settings to Django?

[Here is my Django code]

```
__author__ = 'zhaonanli'
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from models import *
import umpme.settings
import base64


@csrf_exempt
def upload_image_for_profile(request):
    static_dir = umpme.settings.STATIC_ROOT
    users_dir = static_dir + 'users/'

    back_dic = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.raw_post_data:
            try:
                json_data_decoding = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
                big_image_raw_data_b64string = json_data_decoding['big_imageb64string']
                small_image_raw_data_b64string = json_data_decoding['small_imageb64string']
                big_image_raw_data = base64.b64decode(big_image_raw_data_b64string)
                small_image_raw_data = base64.b64decode(small_image_raw_data_b64string)

                uid = json_data_decoding['uid']
                user = UserAccountInfo.objects.get(id=uid)
                uemail = user.usignup_email
                whole_image_dir = users_dir + 'umpme_' + uemail + '_user/'
                bigimage_filename = whole_image_dir + 'bigprofile.jpg'
                smallimage_filename = whole_image_dir + 'smallprofile.jpg'

                bigimage = open(bigimage_filename, 'wb')
                bigimage.write(big_image_raw_data)
                bigimage.close()

                smallimage = open(smallimage_filename, 'wb')
                smallimage.write(small_image_raw_data)
                smallimage.close()

                back_dic['succ'] = 'yes'
                back_dic['error'] = 'nothing'
                back_dic['uid'] = uid

            except Exception, e:
                back_dic['succ'] = 'no'
                back_dic['error'] = 'error = ' + str(e)
                back_dic['uid'] = 'none'
        else:
            back_dic['succ'] = 'no'
            back_dic['error'] = 'cannotgetrawpostdata'
            back_dic['uid'] = 'none'
    else:
        back_dic['succ'] = 'no'
        back_dic['error'] = 'notgetrequest'
        back_dic['uid'] = 'none'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(back_dic), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: webfaction has a SO-like Q&A community, it would be better you put your question there. https://community.webfaction.com/

Comment: Thank you guys. I have found the reason. The reason is that: I should not use "request.raw_post_data:", I should use "request.body:"